# Why is HTTP triggered azure function not being successfully executed by data factory?

Tags: azure-functions, invoke-command, azure-data-factory

I am attempting to connect an HTTP-triggered Azure function with Azure Data Factory(ADF).
My function uses Invoke-AzVMRunCommand to run a PowerShell command on a VM. Though the function works on its own, when triggered by ADF, it shows "successful" when debugging, when I check the VM no changes have been made. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: If you run the command locally does it work ? If you invoke the deployed azure function from postman for example, can you confirm it is working ?

Comment: it works locally and from the function service itself. I have not yet tried postman, I will get back to you on that.